# Laravel - model modifications

Tags: php, laravel

I need to refactor project and I have problem. Below is old, working model, where 'active' column is in "people" table. I need to move 'active' column into "people_translations" table.
Do you have any Idea to modify scopeActive method?
Thanks a lot!

Old working model:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent
{
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where($this->table . '.active', '=', 1);
    }    
}

class People extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'peoples';
    protected $translationModel = 'PeopleTranslation';
}

class PeopleTranslation extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'peoples_translations';
}
```

Old tables structure:

```
Table: peoples
id | type | date | active
-------------------------
7 | .... | ...   | 1


Table: peoples_translations
id | people_id | language_id | name
-----------------------------------
1 |          7 |          1  | Ann
```

Old query:

$peoples = \People::active()->get();

New tables structure:

```
Table: peoples
id | type | date
----------------
7 | .... | ...
```

Table: peoples_translations

```
id | people_id | language_id | name | active
--------------------------------------------
1 |          7 |          1  | Ann  |      1
```

Comment: I don't get why exactly you need the additional table. In what relationship are `People` and `PeopleTanslation`? hasOne? hasMany?

Comment: Tim, there is many language_id for many languages, so hasMany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a relation for translations inside People Model

```
public function translations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PeopleTranslation', 'people_id');
}
```

Create active scope in People model

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('translations', function($query) {
        $query->where('active', 1);
    });
}
```

It will make subquery for this table and as a result it will get where (count of translations with active = 1) > 0.

If you have one-to-one relation - look for hasOne relation method instead of hasMany.

Comment: Thank you for your help Silwerclaw :)